# Flutter How does Firebase Analytics Dashboard Active Users in Last 30 Minutes will work?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

Flutter How does Firebase Analytics Dashboard Active Users in Last 30 Minutes will work ?

I installed application and set userId & User Property its showing one user count in `firebase -> analytics -> dashboard -> active users in last 30 minutes`. And with same user am continuously using application for 5 to 10 minutes but its not showing the count in `dashboard -> active users in last 30 minutes -> per minute users`. It's recorded only one time after that it's not recording again.

`Attached screenshot below`

[image]

here count of 4 user are same because i uninstalled and installed in same device it's counted as new user. But once counted in dashboard if am using application continuously it's not recording again.

Hence, my doubt is if i use application actively 5 to 10 minute it should show my user active count in every minute right until am killing application ? In my case it's showing only one time. If i kill and reopen application also its not showing in active users per minute dashboard.

Comment: I have exactly same symptom. Shows 1 active user only after app is uninstalled/installed, but doesn't show anything when app is opened. Weird.